# can we open gitbash from atom text editor

Tags: git-bash, atom-editor

Is there a way to open gitbash from within atom text editor. I want to have gitbash or other command line client in one of the panes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install https://atom.io/packages/terminal-plus

Then in package options

Shell Override: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe`

Shell Arguments: `-l -i`

Use git >= 2.7.3 for windows, bash starts up much faster.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using the [PlatformIO IDE Terminal](https://atom.io/packages/platformio-ide-terminal), with these settings:

Shell Override: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe`

Shell Arguments: `--login`

Answer (score 1):

[Yes we can!](https://atom.io/packages/terminal-status)

You can also search "terminal-status" in your atom package manager.

Do remember to restart atom for terminal status to begin working. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

(Windows 10, terminal-plus v0.14.5 package, atom v1.8.0, git-bash 2.9.0.1), these quoted parts from the linked discussion work cleanly for me (original source:  https://github.com/jeremyramin/terminal-plus/issues/117):

> **Git Bash opens in new window on Windows (terminal-plus issue #117)**
>
> *matthewcanty (2015-12-03)*:  The default terminal is Powershell, but I want it to be Git Bash.  I have set Shell Override to `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe` but this opens in a new window.
>
> *matthewcanty (2015-12-03, later answering & closing his own question)*:
>
> ```
> Shell Override: C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe
> Shell Arguments: --login
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is https://atom.io/packages/open-terminal-here

Once installed, update the package settings:

Command: `"C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Nuclide Terminal](https://nuclide.io/docs/features/terminal/), with these settings in `$HOME/.nuclide-terminal.json`

```
{
  "command": [
    "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-cmd.exe",
    "--command=usr/bin/bash.exe -l -i"
  ]
}
```